# Negative and Large R^2 value for Random Forest Regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I am new to Machine Learning and Random Forest Regression in general, but I have working a Random Forest Regression model looking at predicting gas concentrations in the atmsophere and have been getting a strange R^2 value of around -228 for one data set (and -.93 for another)

I have the model working for one data set predicting concentrations of Benzene in the atmosphere (R^2 is about .44) but when I apply my model to looking at concentrations of Methane (CH4) it predicts the ~-228 R^2 value.

Running scikit-learn version 1.3.0

Typical values in my .csv after a complete run of my model for Methane (in ppmv):

predictedCH4 (ppmv) observedCH4 (ppmv)  Percent_Error
0.03                    1.947                   98.46
0.08                    1.808                   95.58
0.02                    1.94                    98.97
0.08                    1.944                   95.88
0.25                    1.922                   86.99
0.7                 2.008                   65.14
0.13                    1.863                   93.02
0.09                    1.885                   95.23
0.12                    1.889                   93.65
...

- 3000 rows

As opposed to my typical run for Benzene:
predictedBenzene (E_MS) observedBenzene (E_MS)  Percent_Error
13.14           8           64.25
33.29           11          202.64
22.57           21          7.48
17.63           19          7.21
13.53           15          9.8
16.32           19          14.11
15.7            19          17.37
17.94           15          19.6
14.26           13          9.69
15.81           16          1.19
...

- 3000 rows

There are a few outliers in the data but for the most part it seems that I could at least do better than my model if I predicted a value of "2" for the entire methane dataset.

Is this something wrong with the way I am initializing my model? Is predicting small fluctuations like this via Random Forest Regression usually like this? or is my model truly a horrific predictor of Methane in the atmosphere.

Code is Below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import d2_absolute_error_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
from sklearn.metrics import max_error
from sklearn.tree import export_text
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree

file_path = "C:/Users/.../finalRFInput.csv"

# Load data from CSV into a pandas DataFrame.
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Prediction variable
var_of_int = "CH4 (ppmv)"

data = data.dropna(subset = var_of_int)

# Gets a df of prediction variables. (i.e. temperature, pressure, specific humidity)
predictionBaseVars = data.iloc[:, 16:26]

# Dataframe of variable we are trying to predict
prediction_var = data.loc[:, [var_of_int]]


# Split the data into training and testing sets.
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(predictionBaseVars, prediction_var, test_size=0.2, random_state=1911816)

# Get labels ready for training
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)

# Initialize a Random Forest Regressor.
rf_regressor = RandomForestRegressor() #n_estimators, max_depth, verbose

# Train the Regressor on the training data
rf_regressor.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())

# Make gas concentration predictions
y_pred = rf_regressor.predict(x_test)

# Calculate SciKitLearn model scoring metrics
r2score = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
d2score = d2_absolute_error_score(y_test, y_pred)
MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
EVS = explained_variance_score(y_test, y_pred)
Max_err = max_error(y_test, y_pred)
  

# Print to console
# How well the regression fits the data
print(f"R2 Score: {r2score:.2f}") 
print(f"D2 Score: {d2score:.2f}")
print(f"Mean Squared Error: {MSE:.2f}")
print(f"Explained Variance Score: {EVS:.3f}") 
print(f"Max Error: {Max_err:.2f}")

# Format CSV column name for predicted variable
predicted = 'predicted'
predic_label = predicted + var_of_int


# Predict the target column for the entire dataset 
#  put it into a CSV format with the variables that predicted it
#  add on the correct values
predictionBaseVars[predic_label] = rf_regressor.predict(predictionBaseVars)
predictionBaseVars[var_of_int] = prediction_var

# Calculate percent error manually
def percentErr(true, predicted):
    predictionErr = abs((true - predicted) / true) * 100
    return predictionErr

# Add to Dataframe in preparation for .CSV
predictionBaseVars["Percent_Error"] = round(percentErr(predictionBaseVars[var_of_int], predictionBaseVars[predic_label]), 2)

# Create filepath
filebase = 'C:/Users/.../filepath/'
extension = '.csv'
finalPath = filebase + "predicted" + var_of_int + extension

# Save the updated DataFrame with predictions to a new CSV file.
predictionBaseVars.to_csv(finalPath, index=False)

# Visualize
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
# plot_tree(rf_regressor.estimators_[0], 
#           filled=True, impurity=True, 
#           rounded=True)
```

Comment: If the defaults aren't giving you good results, try changing the parameters and seeing if you get better results. E.g. try increasing `min_samples_leaf=` to have more averaging at the terminal nodes and possibly smoother behaviour. `n_estimators=` is another one to try. Maybe this model won't work as well with your data compared with other models available in `sklearn`.